# Jquery Carousel Weird Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am getting weird Animations in Jquery when trying to convert images inside a `div` into a Carousel. 
Here is the code -

```js
$(function() {
  // vars for clients list carousel
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759494/jquery-function-definition-in-a-carousel-script
  var $clientcarousel = $('.slider');
  var clients = $clientcarousel.children().length;
  var clientwidth = (clients * 200); // 140px width for each client item 
  $clientcarousel.css('width', clientwidth);

  var rotating = true;
  var clientspeed = 0;

  seeclients = setInterval(rotateClients, clientspeed);

  function rotateClients() {
    if (rotating != false) {
      var $first = $('.slider img:first');
      var $last = $('.slider img:last');
      $first.animate({
        'margin-left': '-200px'
      }, 2000, "linear", function() {
        $first.remove().css({
          'margin-left': '0px'
        });
        $('.slider img:last').after($first);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider" dir="ltr">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40" />
</div>
```

Because this part -

```
$first.remove().css({ 'margin-left': '0px' });
$('.slider img:last').after($first);
```

happens after the `animation` function has been executed, it creates a stutter in the carousel flow.

Can anybody tell me how can I make the carousel smooth?

Here is a fiddle with the above code - https://jsfiddle.net/qLtth77k/

**PLUS**: I want the carousel to stop when someone hover over any of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Removing left element, that is out of scene removes it's right margin as well. You need to move it so, that it's margin goes out of scene as well. So changing animation to 
`...
 $first.animate({
        'margin-left': '-230px'
      }, ...`
 
solves the issue

Comment: yes, but the images doesn't appear as smooth in the end as they disappear in the beginning. There is just no animation in the end.